# MySQL JOIN: print left table rows only at first appearance

Tags: mysql, sql, join

There are two tables:

```
    first                 second
+----+------+    +----+----------+-------+
| id | name |    | id | first_id | value |
+----+------+    +----+----------+-------+
|  1 |  one |    |  1 |        1 |    10 |
|  2 |  two |    |  2 |        1 |    11 |
+----+------+    |  3 |        2 |    20 |
                 |  4 |        2 |    22 |
                 +----+----------+-------+
```

**What I have:**

SQL query

```sql
SELECT T1.`id` AS firstId,
       T1.`name` AS name,
       T2.`value` AS value
FROM `first` AS T1
JOIN `second` AS T2
  ON T2.`first_id` = T1.`id`
ORDER BY T1.`id` ASC,
         T2.`id` ASC;
```

Result

```
+---------+------+-------+
| firstId | name | value |
+---------+------+-------+
|       1 |  one |    10 |
|       1 |  one |    11 |
|       2 |  two |    20 |
|       2 |  two |    22 |
+---------+------+-------+
```

**What I want to get:**

I want to omit column values for a left table entry if that entry was in the previous row.

Result

```
+---------+------+-------+
| firstId | name | value |
+---------+------+-------+
|       1 |  one |    10 |
|         |      |    11 |
|       2 |  two |    20 |
|         |      |    22 |
+---------+------+-------+
```

Comment: this is frontend feature not a sql or mysql feature you should manage this at presentation level

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code.

Comment: update your question and show you presentation code  ..

Comment: @scaisEdge, i have no presentation level, I export query results from MySQL to Excel.

Comment: then i have alreay answered by my first comment  ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's my effort:

```
SELECT firstId, name, value FROM
  (SELECT CASE
           WHEN @prev != T1.id THEN @first := 1
           ELSE @first := 0
         END,
         CASE WHEN @first = 1 THEN T1.id ELSE "" END AS firstId,
         CASE WHEN @first = 1 THEN T1.name ELSE "" END AS name,
         T2.value AS value,
         @prev := T1.id
  FROM first AS T1
  INNER JOIN second AS T2
    ON T2.first_id = T1.id
  INNER JOIN (SELECT @prev:=0)f
  ORDER BY T1.id ASC,
           T2.id ASC
   )T
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/38a977/15)

Updated answer for case when table is out of order (we must sort first before we can join with variable).

```
SELECT firstId, name, value FROM
  (SELECT @first := CASE
           WHEN @prev != T1id THEN 1
           ELSE 0
         END,
         CASE WHEN @first = 1 THEN T1id ELSE "" END AS firstId,
         CASE WHEN @first = 1 THEN T1name ELSE "" END AS name,
         T2value AS value,
         @prev := T2first_Id
  FROM (SELECT T1.id as T1id, T2.first_Id as T2first_Id, T1.name as T1name, T2.value as T2value FROM 
        first AS T1
  INNER JOIN second AS T2
    ON T2.first_id = T1.id ORDER BY T1.id ASC,
           T2.id ASC)ORD,(SELECT @prev:=-1)f

   )T
```

[sqlfiddle for when table is out of order](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8e5fca/27)
Or if you prefer to remove the first part to determine @first.

```
SELECT firstId, name, value FROM
  (SELECT CASE WHEN @prev != T1id THEN T1id ELSE "" END AS firstId,
          CASE WHEN @prev != T1id THEN T1name ELSE "" END AS name,
         T2value AS value,
         @prev := T2first_Id
  FROM (SELECT T1.id as T1id, T2.first_Id as T2first_Id, T1.name as T1name, T2.value as T2value FROM 
        first AS T1
  INNER JOIN second AS T2
    ON T2.first_id = T1.id ORDER BY T1.id ASC,
           T2.id ASC)ORD,(SELECT @prev:=-1)f

   )T
```

Comment: I think that removing whole `@first` part and using ` WHEN @prev = T1.id` would look better.

Comment: Somehow it doesn't work as I thought: [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8e5fca/1)

Comment: please see bottom of answer, as table is out of order, you must sort first before you can join with variable table. sqlfiddle at bottom as well. Please check.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT firstId, name, value FROM
  (SELECT CASE WHEN @prevId != T1id THEN T1id ELSE "" END AS firstId,
          CASE WHEN @prevId != T1id THEN T1name ELSE "" END AS name,
         T2value AS value,
         @prevId := T2first_Id
  FROM (SELECT T1.id as T1id, T2.first_Id as T2first_Id, T1.name as T1name, T2.value as T2value FROM 
        first AS T1
  INNER JOIN second AS T2
    ON T2.first_id = T1.id ORDER BY T1.id ASC,
           T2.id ASC)ORD,(SELECT @prevId:=0)f

   )T
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=782203377845b26a5c6af0d803d71190

Updated the answer, so that anyone in future who is looking at the posts will only see correct answer, just a copy of @Tin Tran 's answer.

P.S. I Upvoted his post

Comment: Go on then. Why not share that?

Comment: yes, better to share as a fiddle. A starting link might be : https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6

Comment: hope this new link helps

Comment: OK, that works for more then two second rows per one first row: `CASE WHEN @previous_id = T1.id THEN '' ELSE T1.id END as id, @previous_id := T1.id as previous_id`

Comment: can you update question or paste insert queries to make me understand the data and where it is failing

Comment: @Sameer, it seems I failed to test it correctly first time. I think that you have excess `@prev_name:=` for `displayName` now.

Comment: Did you mean in fiddle.. might be.. code in the answer is correct.. that part I can assure

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=90487834b793c44e73b20a7e77befa0f
updated fiddle as well

Comment: Here: [dbfiddle.uk](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=7359155c8d545282bbd5ee58c809e3b8)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198190/discussion-between-sameer-and-sui-dream).